# How to REWRITE a folder name in web.config with a different name?

Tags: iis, web-config

I know my way around .htaccess files a bit but not really web.config files. There are many questions about this on here and I hate to ask a duplicate but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's what I am trying to do.

I need to convert this URL:

```
https://www.website.com/some-stuff-here/replacethis/some-more-stuff-here
```

To this URL:

```
https://www.website.com/some-stuff-here/foobar/some-more-stuff-here
```

I need to replace **replacethis** with **foobar**

Here's what I've tried:

```
<rule name="Rewrite for Foobar">
    <match url="^replacethis/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="^foobar/{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="Rewrite for Foobar">
    <match url="^/(.*)/replacethis/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="^/{R:1}/foobar/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

I don't know what I'm doing help me. :(

Comment: Why is this question tagged `.htaccess`?

Comment: @arkascha you are right. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule to achieve your requirement.

Notice: you shoud replace the localhost url to your example url.

```
            <rule name="Rewrite for Foobar1">
              <match url="^replacethis/(.*)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8082/foobar/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="foldername">
                <match url="(.*)/replacethis/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8082/{R:1}/foobar/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]